# Get url of Image in GAE (Python 2.7)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to get URL of Image(blob field of GAE):

```
class Product(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  price = db.FloatProperty()
  added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  image = db.BlobProperty(default=None)


url = images.get_serving_url(movie.image)
```

Handler of serve image:

```
def result(request):
  product = Product()
  product.name = "halva"
  url = 'http://echealthinsurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/minnesota.jpg'
  product.image = db.Blob(urlfetch.Fetch(url).content)
  product.put()

  template = loader.get_template("result.html")
  context = RequestContext(request, 
                         {
        "result" : u"Add"})

  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

But i get except:

```
UnicodeDecodeError:
```

When try to ignore this exception(that was bug in Python 2.7) I get exception in other place.

And after that i try to encode Image to 'latin-1'('utf-8' don't work):

```
 enc_img = movie.image.decode("latin-1")
 url = images.get_serving_url(enc_img)
```

Result: url has a view like binary file:

```
 "ÝêÓ9>èýÑNëCf Äàr0xã³3Ï^µ7±\íQÀ¡>.....ÕÝ£°Ëÿ"I¢¶L`ù¥ºûMþÒ¸ÿ+ÿL¢ï£ÿÙ' alt="" />"
```

How I get url to show dynamic image in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different things here.

If you are storing your image in a db.BlobProperty (code doesn't show you are doing this, but the Schema you have is using db.BlobProperty) this means your handler has to serve the image.

However you are using image.get_serving_url, which takes a BlobKey instance which comes from storing an Image in the BlobStore https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobkeyclass   which is a completely different thing to what you are doing.

You will need to work out what you want to do, store an image (max size 1MB) in a BlobProperty and provide a handler that can serve the image, or upload it to the BlobStore and serve it from there

Answer (score 0):

`images.get_serving_url` takes a BlobKey. Try:

```
enc_img = movie.image
url = images.get_serving_url(enc_img.key())
```

Comment: AttributeError: "'Blob' object has no attribute 'key'"